# Lock Windows keyboard and mouse but still display screen normally

Tags: windows-7, lock-screen

I'm using windows 7, I have a dual monitor display. It displays important information related to the business, I'd rather that random users that walk in can't just walk over to it and start using the computer with the same access rights as the user the monitoring software is running as.

What I would like is if any time someone presses a button on the keyboard including alt-ctrl-delete all that would appear is a dialog asking for a password.

Then I can click cancel and it will return to showing the data I want displayed.

ClearLock doesn't work I tried it btw

Comment: Sounds like you want to be able to view the screen until someone tries to use the computer, then it locks. Am I hearing you correctly?

Comment: Commonly called "kiosk mode" for which you will get lots more hits when searching the web. One example is Interset's Secure Lockdown v2 (http://shop.inteset.com/Products/9-lock-down-windows-7-with-inteset-secure-lockdown.aspx)